# How to hide CheckBox in DataGridView if value of cell is null

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have Winform with `DataGridView` filled from table which contains `bit` columns.
I need to hide the `CheckBox` if the values is `null`, and keep it visible if the value is `true` or `false`.

How do I hide `CheckBox` in `DataGridView` if value of cell is `null`?

Comment: Handle [`CellPainting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?view=netframework-4.8) event and don't draw the check box in case the value of cell is null/dbnull

Comment: Where did you get the `dataSource`? is it from query?

Comment: Syaiqur, it's DB SP

Comment: Reza Aghaei, How to not draw checkbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle [CellPainting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event and don't draw the check box in case the value of cell is `null` or `DBNnull.Value`:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 1 && 
       (e.Value == DBNull.Value || e.Value == null))
    {
        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All &
            ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Note:

- `e.RowIndex >= 0` Makes sure we are rendering the data cells, not the header cells.
- `e.ColumnIndex == 1` Makes sure we are applying the logic for the column at index 1. If you want the logic for another column, use فhat column's index.
- `e.Paint(...);` Is paining all parts of the cell, except the cell content foreground which is the check box.
- `e.Handled = true;` Sets the painting as handled, so the default paint logic will not run.
- It doesn't make the cell read-only. It just skips rendering the checkbox.
- Don't forget to add the event handler to the event.